# On the right track -> to distract

Tags: etymology, roots

It sounds that `distracting` and `being on the right track` are related not only by meaning but also by common roots. Is the track that we see in `distracting` related etymologically to the track in the word `track`?

---

> track (n.) Look up track at Dictionary.com late 15c., "footprint, mark
>   left by anything," from Old French trac "track of horses, trace"
>   (mid-15c.), possibly from a Germanic source (compare Middle Low German
>   treck, Dutch trek "drawing, pulling;" see trek). Meaning "lines of
>   rails for drawing trains" is from 1805. Meaning "branch of athletics
>   involving a running track" is recorded from 1905. Meaning "single
>   recorded item" is from 1904, originally in reference to phonograph
>   records. Meaning "mark on skin from repeated drug injection" is first
>   attested 1964.

---

> distract (v.) Look up distract at Dictionary.com mid-14c., "to draw
>   asunder or apart, to turn aside" (literal and figurative), from Latin
>   distractus, past participle of distrahere "draw in different
>   directions," from dis- "away" (see dis-) + trahere "to draw" (see
>   tract (n.1)).

---

> tract (n.1) Look up tract at Dictionary.com "area," mid-15c., "period
>   or lapse of time," from Latin tractus "track, course, space,
>   duration," lit, "a drawing out or pulling," from stem of trahere "to
>   pull, draw," from PIE root *tragh- "to draw, drag, move" (cognates:
>   Slovenian trag "trace, track," Middle Irish tragud "ebb;" perhaps with
>   a variant form *dhragh-; see drag (v.)). The meaning "stretch of land
>   or water" is first recorded 1550s. Specific U.S. sense of "plot of
>   land for development" is recorded from 1912; tract housing attested
>   from 1953.

I see no clear connection in the sources. The dictionary says that `tract` originated from `track` in 15c whereas `track` was derived from `trek` only in 19c. This does not make sense at all!

Comment: When you look in reference materials for the etymology of distract, what do you see?  Can you edit your question to add those references and why the reference information doesn't tell you what you want to know?  Etymonline.com is an easy to use reference for this kind of question.

Comment: If you google "etymology of distract" and "etymology of track" you will find the answer quite quickly. :-)

Comment: @Nonnal Yes, I see my question in google. There was no way to solve my problem before I posted it!

Comment: I just meant that Google.com has a nice etymology search feature. In any event, nice update to your original post. It is extremely common in English for two words with similar spellings to come from different roots.